# cannot display new content

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using drupal 7 and i have been having this issue where i am trying to add a new page onto an existing drupal site but all I'm getting is one content (the page title and some body text) displaying.all the content types which include some images that eventually build up the page are  published but are not displaying on the final live site even after clearing the cache both on admin/config/development/performance/cache and on phpmyadmin.i have also created a page--mynewpage--tpl.php page for that page.i believe i have done all the url's correctly.while adding the content types, i referenced the previous working pages just to make sure that i was filling all the required fields so as to have some uniformity within the site
What could i be missing out on, since i added the link of my new page to the page.tpl.php.
I have been trying to get a solution for this for a week now and any assistance form you will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

are you inserting "inline images" into your content type body-field (1) or using an image field at your content type (2)?

1) Inline images are inserted with an  tag which is stripped out by the standard text formatter (filtered html). Either use the "full html" formatter or (better) make a new text formatter which includes  tags for allowed html tags. Full html is normally below body field at the content edit form.
To add a text formatter (or edit filtered html) go to `admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html` and add the  tag (including the bracers) into the allowed html tags field.

2) If you are using an image field try to change the image field formatter to "image" and set format settings to a image style like "medium".

Greetings, krueschi

Comment: Thank you @krueschi for your time and answer.
I am using an image field and the suggestion you gave is what is used by all the other pages and images of the site.Could it be something else that im missing out on?This is how my page looks like when it loads up, it doesnt display all the content.

http://simbacolt.com/mitsubishi/asx. and would rather look like this 
http://simbacolt.com/mitsubishi/lancer

Comment: On the upper part there seems to be an (flex-) slider active, so I concentrate on the lower part ("Model variants"): There are some views module classes and I suspect, that `view-display-id-default` has some impact. Try to change the views display formatter to an (or an other) image style. Helpful could be also to post an export of your view here.

Comment: A second thought: Your example page misses several views classes that the other pages have; is the field-naming identical? / (Additionally: If you are using memcached or varnish: empty that caches too.)

Comment: Hi krueschi,i figured it out,the issue was beacuse my newpage.tpl.php i had named it wrongly before it was page--node--asx.tpl.php which i renamed to page--node--644.tpl.php and somehow all seems to work now.thank you again for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Nice to read. BUT do you really need a specific page--[].tpl.php for this one and only "page" (= node 644)? Maybe a more generic page.tpl.php and then f.i. a node--[car-type-content-type or whatever].tpl.php would be a better (read: cleaner) way ([Theming handbook page on d.o](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656))